# Where does music downloaded from Google Play go on my phone?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, google-play-music

New Nexus 6 with Lollipop. I downloaded some music from Google Play, but cannot for the life of me find where it is on the phone. I've searched through the entire thing using Astro, and can't find my music. (The Play app sees it, but I want to make one of my songs a ringtone, and apparently with Lollipop, you need to copy your file into a certain location for it to be available.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that's not possible. Like with iTunes, Google uses DRM (**D**igital **R**ights **M**anagement) technology in order to prevent you from illegally copying music. So, the music is stored on your phone in an encoded way and thus you can only access the music through the Google Play app.