# Can't find music I downloaded from Google play music

Tags: google, google-play-music

I just downloaded the Google play music subscription and downloaded a bunch of music that is supposed to download to my SD card but cannot find any of my music and its also not downloading to my SD card. Almost any app or music I try downloading or moving to my SD card says it's downloaded or moved but doesn't move it stays on the phones memory. Don't want to keep paying for this music subscription if I can't access my music I downloaded, and need to figure out why my phone memory doesn't free up space when I move to my SD card. I have the SD card and another external memory device that says I can transfer my media and most times it says I did move them but I don't get any free space on my phone afterwards. I also cannot find anything in downloading mainly music I'm worried about now since I'm paying for this subscription, if you can please help me out that would be great.  Thank-you for your time only got this phone less then a month ago and I'm having a lot of problems already, cannot receive texts or phone calls when I'm online or in a game. Pretty much of anything is running on the phone nothing will come through and phone won't even ring, only way I know I have a missed call is if a message is left and that takes awhile to come through.

Comment: See: [Where does music downloaded from Google Play go on my phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/101085/16575). Apart from that: your question is a "big wall of text" and very hard to read: almost no punctuation, no paragraphs. Most people will just skip it because of that. Please, work on your formatting (and remember: you can always [edit] your post to improve it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does Google Music store offline songs?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16220/where-does-google-music-store-offline-songs)

Answer (score 2):

Google Play Music app is storing music files in your phone's internal memory, which means that you can't access them without root access.
They are located in `/data/data/com.google.android.music/files/music` folder. To access them you need to root your phone.

But if your phone is not rooted, going to this folder will show your downloaded files named something like `1123.mp3 / 1234.mp3` and etc.
You will have all your files, but name of artists, tracks and everything else is erased from mp3 file's metadata.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My music don't download either even after it says download complete. Also I couldnt hear my ringtone when I got a call. For this I wrote down all the apps and contacts I had  and I reset my phone. That worked and freed up a lot of space on my phone from the built up misc. files I had.

Hope this helps if you haven't figured it out already.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after racking my brain. When you open Google Play, swipethe menu left until you open PLAYLISTS. Then it should have a playlist saying "most recent" or along those lines. When you open the list up, click the little download circle with the arrow down, and it downloads to the SD card. At least it worked for me. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for music in a particular folder - a folder called "Music". Nothing more, nothing less. If your music is in a folder otherwise named, it won't find it